# Python Requests Logging into a website

Tags: python, url, redirect, authentication

Heyo,

Able to log into my school website using requests and the .post method
(Trying to create a feed showing when new results are up)

```
url = "https://pipeline.tsc.nsw.edu.au/scots/pages/main/login.php"
payload = {'username': 'my.name', 'password': 'password'}

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.post(url, data=payload)
    print(r.text) # Write to file and create filter to check against old code
```

The difficulty I'm having is that the website seems to generate a url for you with an 'eduId' in the browser bar e.g

```
https://pipeline.tsc.nsw.edu.au/scots/pages/mainframe.php?eduId=3993834&displayID=&theme=scots&version=4.2.2&demo=-1
```

You're redirected to this url when you successfully login to the site but I can't seem to get it with requests.

Does anybody know how to handle the redirect or gather the redirected URL? Thanks

NOTE: For all I can tell the login is either not taking place or not registering the redirect as the incorrect login message doesn't show up in the downloaded code

Comment: Will you please check what return code you got when you do `request.post`? If it is 3XX means its redirect, you will get url in request.body. Please past what you get in `r.text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you take a look at the Mechanize python lib, Mechanize behaves like a browser and make it simpler to handle sessions, redirects etc. 
http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/

Comment: Looks great at first glance, will play around with it a bit more now. Thanks heaps